# foreach loop running through curl function

Tags: php, digital-ocean

I've been scratching my head for days over this stupid one.

I have an array of urls called $url_array pulled from the database like so -

```
Array (
    [id] => 2
    [url] => http://example.com
)
```

I have foreach loop which runs over $url_array and scrapes the url for data like so -

```
foreach ($url_array as $row) {
    $data = $this->scrapePage($row["url"]);
    print_r($data);
    return false;
}
```

Currently $data is outputting nothing. But if I replace $row["url"] with http://example.com, the scrape happens correctly.

This is the first time I've also hosted this script on DigitalOcean so I'm not sure if there are any server technicalities possibly stopping a foreach loop from working.

edit:
Here is the scrapePage function -

```
private function scrapePage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Charset: utf-8'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $header = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return array("header" => $header, "content" => $content);
}
```

Like I said, if I manually enter a url in there, it works fine, just not when in a loop.

As for the $url_array, this is the output when I print it out -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41
            [url] => http://www.example1.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [url] => http://test-url-2.com
        )
)
```

I've also tried a for loop over the data. If I modify the scrapePage function to return the $url, it returns the $url correctly.

Comment: can you please post your scrapePage function

Comment: Is `$url_array` exactly as the array you posted above?  Or is that just _one_ subarray from a larger, multidimensional array that you are not showing?

Comment: Just debug into `scrapePage` or add a log-statement to it, logging `$url` -- see whats really happening.

Comment: @TomRegner can you please elaborate on how to do that? All I've done is print the $row["url"] value going into the function, and from scrapePage, I return the $url straight away and I get the same url. But if I use $this->scrapePage("http://example.com"); it works fine

Comment: If you manually create an array of 2-3 URLs and iterate over it does it work? If yes then maybe try to create it, iterate over both at once(`$key=>$row`) and compare(===) the URLs from file and db arrays. If no then try to add `sleep(2)` in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much headache, I've found the issue. The database of urls I had looked like this -

```
http://www.example1.com\r
http://www.example2.com\r
http://www.example3.com\r
http://www.example4.com\r
```

Note the "\r" at the end, that was messing up cURL. I had assumed the database I was given was clean. Apparently not! I just removed all the trailing \r's and all the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your $url_array is nested, you should try following to get the urls and use your scrapePage function:

```
foreach ($url_array as $row => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $row => $value) {
        if($row === 'url') {
        //$urls[]=$value;
        $data = $this->scrapePage($value);
        print_r($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same result unfortunately. All content and header data